# Как вывести среднее значение и все значения выше этого среднего?

Tags: mysql, sql

Надо, чтобы в финальной таблице отображалось среднее значение цены и все названия продуктов значения которые выше средней цены, которую мы вывели:

```
SELECT 'Name', 'Price' 
FROM 'Products' 
WHERE 'Price' > (SELECT AVG('Price') FROM 'Products')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну очевидно же, что подзапрос надо перевести в источник данных - выводить можно только значения из него. Так что

```
SELECT Products.Name, Products.Price, avg_price.avg_price 
FROM Products 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(Price) avg_price FROM Products) avg_price 
WHERE Products.Price > avg_price.avg_price
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fd9736963ff93f04f136537beffdd8b)

PS. Внимательно следите, какие кавычки используете. Это **критически** важно.

Comment: извините, но с вашим запросом что то не получается, не могли бы вы на примере этой таблицы построить запрос - www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: @user429746 Fiddle добавил. *с вашим запросом что то не получается* Невнимательность в процессе адаптации. Тупой копипаст - не поможет, надо ещё и голову приложить.